# Duda con respecto a punteros constantes y punteros a constante

Tags: c, punteros

Mi duda es la siguiente:

Según la teoría dice que un puntero constante no puede cambiar la dirección en el que se encuentra pero si el valor.

Por qué me muestra direcciones distintas al compilar? Por ejemplo la dirección de x me dice que es 2293436 y al momento de asignarle al puntero cambia a otra distinta que no es ni la dirección de x ni la dirección de y

Lo mismo pasa con los punteros a constantes la dirección no es similar

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){

int x=10, y=20;
int q=30, z=40;
int *const p = &x;
const int *ptr = &q;

printf("El valor de x %d",x);
printf("\nEl valor de y: %d\n\n",y);

printf("La direccion de x %d",&x);
printf("\nLa direccion de y: %d\n",&y);

printf("\nEl valor es %d y su direccion es: %d",*p,&p);

*p = y;// CAMBIA VALOR

 printf("\nEl valor es %d y su direccion es: %d");

printf("El valor de q %d",q);
printf("\nEl valor de z: %d\n\n",z);

printf("La direccion de q %d",&q);
printf("\nLa direccion de z: %d\n\n",&z);

printf("El valor es %d y su direccion es: %d\n",*ptr,&ptr);

ptr = &z;

printf("El valor es %d y su direccion es: %d",*ptr,&ptr);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Si quieres imprimir el valor y la dirección de memoria a la que apunta el puntero debes imprimir `*p` y `p` respectivamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que un diagrama puede ayudarte a entender tu confusión. Supongamos que has declarado e inicializado las variables tal como empieza tu programa:

```
int x=10, y=20;
int q=30, z=40;
int *const p = &x;
const int *ptr = &q;
```

Cada una de esas declaraciones reserva un trozo de memoria del tamaño apropiado para el tipo que va a contener. Digamos, por simplificar, que un entero ocupa 4 bytes y que un puntero también ocupa 4 bytes (de hecho esto es así en arquitecturas de 32 bits). Entonces en este ejemplo, desde el punto de vista de la cantidad de memoria que ocupan, todos tus datos serían iguales, ocupando 4 bytes, si bien lo que significan esos 4 bytes es diferente según se trate de un entero o de un puntero.

Supongamos también que la primera variable en ser almacenada será `x` y que ésta se almacenará en la dirección 20400 (en hexadecimal). En realidad, ya que ocupa 4 bytes, estará en las direcciones 20400, 20401, 20402 y 20403. La siguiente variable sería `y` que estaría en 20404 (y sucesivas), etc.

El siguiente diagrama muestra en qué dirección queda cada variable y qué contiene tras las asignaciones anteriores (los colores se explican después)

[image: Figura 1]

Como ves, `x` está en la dirección 20400 y su contenido (los 4 bytes allí guardados) se interpretan como el número 10, pues eso es lo que le hemos asignado. De forma análoga las variables `y`, `q` y `z` son también fáciles de comprender.

Vamos con los punteros. Con independencia de si es un puntero a entero, o si es `const` o no lo es, un puntero no es más que un trozo de memoria donde se guadará *otra dirección de memoria*. Por tanto el tamaño de un puntero es el tamaño de las direcciones de memoria. En una arquitectura de 32 bits, las direcciones son de 32 bits y por tanto los punteros serían de 32/8 = 4 bytes.

El puntero `p` lo has inicializado con `&x`, por eso vemos que su "valor" es 20400. El valor de un puntero es una dirección de memoria. El que hayas declarado el puntero como "puntero a int" indica que en la dirección a la que apunta se espera un entero.

Análogamente el puntero `ptr` se ha inicializado con `&q` por lo que contiene el "valor" 20408.

Una vez tenemos estas variables `p` y `ptr` tenemos que podemos usar las siguientes sintaxis con ellas (lo explico con `p` pero todo esto es igualmente válido para `ptr`)

- `p` representa a la propia variable. Si intentamos cambiar `p` estaríamos intentando cambiar el valor 20400 que contiene (sombreado en rojo en la imagen). Es decir, si intentamos hacer `p = otro valor`. Esto no es diferente de lo que ocurre cuando intentas cambiar por ejemplo `x` haciendo `x = otro valor`. También si imprimes el "valor" de `p` mediante `printf("%p\n", p)` verías el 20400 que contiene.
- `*p` representa el valor "apuntado por" `p`, es decir, lo que haya en la dirección 20400, que en este caso es `x`. Por tanto imprimir `*p` mostraría 10 en este caso. Y un intento de cambiar `*p` por ejemplo haciendo `*p=200` escribiría ese valor (200) en la dirección 20400, por tanto modificando indirectamente el valor de `x`.
- `&p` esto nos daría la dirección en la que se guarda la propia variable `p` (de la misma forma que `&x` nos da la dirección en que está la variable `x`). En este caso nos daría 20410 como se ve en la figura. Ese valor no puede cambiarse.

Dicho todo esto, vamos con tu pregunta.

### Diferencia entre puntero constante y puntero a constante

#### Puntero constante

Un puntero constante (`p`) es uno al que no puedes cambiar su "valor", es decir, no puedes cambiar la dirección a la que apunta. En la figura significa que la celda marcada en rojo **no se puede modificar**.

Desde el punto de vista de la sintaxis, significa que no puedes intentar esto:

```
p = &y;
```

es decir, hacer que `p` apunte a un lugar diferente del que apuntaba. Si lo intentas tendrás error de compilación. Observa que tu código nunca intentaba esto. Lo que intentaba tu código era esto otro:

```
*p = y
```

Eso no está prohibido, porque eso no está cambiando la celda marcada en rojo, sino la celda marcada en verde (es decir, cambias el valor de `x` y lo dejas al final con el valor 20, tomado de la variable `y`). Por eso he pintado la flecha en verde en la figura. Modificar `*p` es posible. Es `p` lo que no puedes modificar.

Tras esa línea la memoria queda así:

[image: Figura 2]

Por cierto que mostrar `&p` como tú hacías no es útil para comprender lo que está pasando. Lo que tienes que mostrar es `p`. Como antes dije `&p` no puede cambiarse, es la misma durante todo el programa (y eso vale para cualquier variable, `&x`, `&q`, etc...) Al imprimir `&p`  ves ese valor que te confundía porque "no era la dirección de x ni la de y". ¡Claro, era la dirección del propio `p`!

#### Puntero **a** constante

Un puntero a un valor constante (`ptr`) es un puntero para el cual está prohibido modificar el valor al que apunta. Es decir, está prohibido hacer:

```
*ptr = z;
```

Eso intentaría modificar lo que hay en la dirección 20408, que he marcado en tono violeta en la figura (y que es `q` en este caso). Si intentas añadir la línea anterior, tendrás un error de compilación. El valor al que apunta está "protegido". Por eso he pintado la flecha en rojo.

Sin embargo nada te impide modificar el propio puntero `ptr` (lo que hay en la dirección 20414), que es de hecho lo que intentabas en tu programa:

```
ptr = &z;
```

Eso es perfectamente válido y lo que hace es cambiar el 20408 que había en `ptr` por un `2040C`, de modo que ahora `ptr` quedaría apuntando a `z` (y sería `z` la que quedaría "protegida" frente a cambios vía `*ptr`).

Tras esta asignación la memoria queda así:

[image: Figura 3]

### Nota final

Nada te impide tener un puntero constante que apunte a un valor constante. La declaración sería:

```
const int *const cptr = &z;  // Por ejemplo
```

En este caso ya no te dejará reasignar un valor a `cptr` para que apunte a otro lugar, ni tampoco te dejará asignar un valor a `*cptr` para cambiar el entero al que está apuntando.

Comment: Hay un error en el diagrama. `ptr` debería ser **20414**

Comment: @Mateo Tienes razón, muchas gracias por señalarlo! Arreglado!

Comment: @abulafia Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta, me ayudó mucho a entender más sobre punteros, que grande

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer habían advertencias en la compilación ya que para mostrar direcciones o punteros hay que emplear el argumento %p dentro de printf().

Además en una orden printf() había argumentos % pero no variables.

Le dejo aquí el código corregido:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){

int x=10, y=20;
int q=30, z=40;
int *const p = &x;
const int *ptr = &q;

printf("El valor de x %d",x);
printf("\nEl valor de y: %d\n\n",y);

printf("La direccion de x %p",&x);
printf("\nLa direccion de y: %p\n",&y);

printf("\nEl valor es %d y su direccion es: %p",*p,&p);

*p = y;// CAMBIA VALOR

**printf("\nEl valor es %d y su direccion es: %p", *p,&p);** // Faltaba -> , *p,&p

printf("El valor de q %d",q);
printf("\nEl valor de z: %d\n\n",z);

printf("La direccion de q %p",&q);
printf("\nLa direccion de z: %p\n\n",&z);

printf("El valor es %d y su direccion es: %p\n",*ptr,&ptr);

ptr = &z;

printf("El valor es %d y su direccion es: %p",*ptr,&ptr);

return 0;
}
```

Espero que le sirva. Un saludo.